# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask

I have a function that should be applied to some dataframe to make some calculations. As dataframe is pretty big in aim to speed up calculations I decided to choose Dask for parallel pandas processing

I have following code:
https://pastebin.com/Zh672Wei

The main issue is with these lines:

```
crosses_data.apply((lambda row: calculate_vwap(row[0], row[1], row[2], vwap_data, row.name)), axis=1)
```

Code above works.
The same code, but parallelized with dask fails with error 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns':

```
dd.from_pandas(crosses_data,npartitions=4).map_partitions(
      lambda df : df.apply((lambda row: calculate_vwap(row[0], row[1], row[2], vwap_data, row.name)), axis=1)).\
   compute(scheduler=get)
```

I used official docs for dask and this error really make now sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is some sort of magic, but solution is following:.
calculate_vwap function should have a touple as an output:

```
def calculate_vwap(ric_id, interval_start, interval_finish, vwap_data, row_n):
    some_tmp_vwap_interval_data = \
        vwap_data.query(
            'TKER == @ric_id and interval > @interval_start and interval < '
            '@interval_finish '
        )[['IVWP', 'INTV']]
    if sum(some_tmp_vwap_interval_data['INTV']):
        return \
            sum(
                vwap * volume for vwap, volume in
                zip(some_tmp_vwap_interval_data['IVWP'],
                    some_tmp_vwap_interval_data['INTV'])
            ) \
            / sum(some_tmp_vwap_interval_data['INTV']), \
            some_tmp_vwap_interval_data.IVWP.iloc[0], \
            some_tmp_vwap_interval_data.IVWP.iloc[-1], \
            some_tmp_vwap_interval_data.INTV.sum()

    return None
```

after that this output should be converted to a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(
                dd.from_pandas(crosses_data[[
                    'RIC', 'Interval_Start_Human',
                    'Interval_End_Human']],
                               npartitions=int(partitions_number)).
                map_partitions(
                    lambda df: df.apply((
                        lambda row: calculate_vwap(row[0],
                                                   row[1],
                                                   row[2],
                                                   vwap_data,
                                                   row.name)),
                                        axis=1)).
                compute(scheduler=get).values.tolist())
```